# Webscraping the food menu

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-2.7, scrape

I am trying to scrape the daily menu but I get everything else but the menu. I tried to insert everything including "left-div item-name" but that I get NONE. Any idea?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
import requests
import pandas as pd
from simple_colors import *
url = "http://www.restauraceumajeru.cz/denni-menu"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
def daily_menu():
    menu = soup.findAll("body")
    for item in menu:
        print(item.text)
daily_menu()
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'insert everything.' The xpath for the 'left-div item-name' element is: /html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]. In order to extract data from that element, you need to target that xpath.

Comment: thank you . I am trying to get the daily menu from that page so I meant I was trying to insert all kind of elements to get the daily menu. How did you find out that xpath?

Comment: No problem. In varies for each browser, but you right click on the element on the page, then click inspect to open the inspector. From there you can select the element you want to target and copy the css or xpath for the element.